# Can't read slash ( / ) with Scanner Java

Tags: java, math, operation

I want to check if an user types a mathematical character with scanner.hasNext("[-+/*]") and it seems to not detect the "/" operation.

```
public void checkSign(Scanner scanner) {
        for (;!scanner.hasNext("[-+/*]");) {
                  System.err.println("You have not typed an operation (ex: + , - , * , /)!");
                  System.out.println("Try again!");
                  scanner.next();
             } 
    }
```

Comment: Try with `[-+\/*]`

Comment: "illegal escape character" error occurs...

Comment: @maria_so double the backslash: `"[-+\\/*]"`

Comment: Works for me. JDK 13.0.1 on Windows 10. What leads you to the conclusion that the forward slash character, i.e. `/`, is not _detected_?

Comment: is not detected meaning that it enters the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by not using any kind of regex but instead checking if the input is contained in the operations string like this:

```
public String checkSign(Scanner scanner) {  
    String line;
    scanner.nextLine();
    for (;!"+-*/".contains(line = scanner.nextLine());) {
               System.err.println("You have not typed an operand! (ex: + , - , * , /)!");
               System.out.println("Try again!");
               scanner.next();
    } 
    return line;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Slash character is identified using `\\/` pattern

Update your pattern to `[-+\\/*]`

Comment: Extra detail: the double is because the Java string itself would use it as an escape character as a single.  Double let's the backslash literal get to the regex.

Comment: Do one thing. Remove other operators and just try the slash one and see if it works.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine. I didn't see `You have not typed an...` error when I gave `/` input on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)) class as per below:

```
Pattern.matches("([/+-.*])", typed)
```

Here is an example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String typed = null;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    typed = scanner.next();
    if (Pattern.matches("([/+-.*])", typed)) {
        System.out.println("typed[/+-*]: " + typed);
    } 
}
scanner.close();
```

output:

```
3
2
1
/
typed[/+-*]: /
*
typed[/+-*]: *
-
typed[/+-*]: -
+
typed[/+-*]: +
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use \\ / instead of /

```
public void checkSign(Scanner scanner) {
        for (;!scanner.hasNext("[-+\\/*]");) {
                  System.err.println("You have not typed an operation (ex: + , - , * , /)!");
                  System.out.println("Try again!");
                  scanner.next();
             } 
    }
```